# StandOutWindow Spinner Unable To add window -- Token is null

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-spinner

I have looked all over the internet, and I am well aware to the threads in stackOverflow about this subject, but non of them helped me.

In my Application I am using Standout open source library to enable non full screen windows, basically what it does is to create Frame Layout and show it with

```
WindowManager.addView(View view, LayoutParams params)
```

inside the FrameLayout I have Spinner view to show drop down list.
when I start the application its all working fine, I can see the FrameLayout and the spinner,
but when I touch the spinner the apllication crash with an error: "Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application"

I dont have any line of code using getApplicationContext(), although Standout library had, I changed them to point 'this' and it still crash.

can anyone help me?

**EDIT:** its only happens on 2.3.5 devices (from what i checked), works fine on 4.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the Standout window is not an activity. Its just a AlertWindow type. Clicking on Spinner will tries to show a dialog box which assumes launched from the activity. But it is not. Then app crash happens. To solve this issue you have to extend the Spinner to show the list view dialog like spinner shows when user clicks on Spinner.
Try below code to show dialog from a not-activity class:

```
  public class MySpinner extends Spinner {
    @Override
    public boolean performClick() {

      // the spinner click is handled here
        selectedPosition = getSelectedItemPosition();
        Dialog dialog = getDialog();
        Window window = dialog.getWindow();
        window.getAttributes().type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT;
        dialog.show();
      }
      return true;
    }

  private Dialog getDialog() {
       AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());

       View dialogView = inflate(getContext(),R.layout.spin_dialog, null);
       builder.setView(dialogView);

       // show the Spinner array list in a listview
       ListView listview = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.spin_list);
       listview.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
       listview.setOnItemClickListener(this);
       ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.list_item, spinner_array_list);

      // here is your spin adapter
      listview.setAdapter(adapter);

      builder.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
         @Override
         public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
              dialog.dismiss();
         }
      });
      AlertDialog dialog = catBuilder.create();
      return dialog;
    }
  }
```

Comment: It is not work, the code is incomplete, and syntax error, also no mention about layout. Also The method setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) in the type AdapterView<ListAdapter> is not applicable for the arguments (MySpinner)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Solution is fairly simple. You just need to add in your layout XML file:

```
android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
```

So your spinner element will look something like this:

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spLists"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
```